# How do I get integer String output into Android Studio's Logcat?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-logcat

I have a bunch of EditTexts that are set up with int Strings to capture their length.  I want to show the lengths in LogCat to confirm they have been set up correctly.  I read about using LogCat, tags and how to filter but need some advice on how to add Log code to get output to LogCat.

Here is an example of the int String I am looking to calculate length for:

```
public class CardViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String tag = "CLOCKS";
private ListenerEditText eListenerEditText;

eListenerEditText.setKeyImeChangeListener(new KeyImeChange() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            int stringNotes2 = eListenerEditText.getText().toString().trim().length();
            Log.d("CLOCKS", String.valueOf(stringNotes2));
```

Comment: Did you try the following - `Log.d("MYAPPTAG", String.valueOf(stringDueDate))`;

Comment: Android Studio doesn't like the Log.d.  It says "Cannot resolve symbol 'd'."  Also, says "Cannot resolve symbol 'valueOf'."
And says "Cannot resolve symbol 'stringDueDate'."

Please advise.

Comment: That's weird!! Can you post the complete code?

Comment: Sure, I edited question above to include your Log.d line.
Also, I checked that Android Studio automatically imported "android.util.Log" with the addition of your Log.d line.

Comment: Did you put this code inside onCreate() method of your Activity?

Comment: In case you have a fragment then put it inside onActivityCreated() method of your fragment.

Comment: Perhaps you should choose one of log levels (top-right) in Logcat windows to view it. Try Log.i(...) and choose "Verbose" to see if it works

Comment: Ok, it looks like I need to include your line in the onCreate code where the ListenerEditTexts are defined.  But it still doesn't like the "stringDueDate".  Any ideas?

Comment: Would be awesome If you can put the whole class code here? so I can help you fast

Comment: Ok I just edited to include all relevant code.  Notice I put in another more simple EditText reference.

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, please mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Log.d() must be called in somewhere like onCreate(..) {..} or some type of method.

for example,

```
// This is wrong
public class Hello {
  Log.d("hello","hi");

  ...
}
```

Make sure you call methods in some type of methods.

```
// This is correct
public class Hello extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d("Hello","Hi");
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You shoud declare your log tag:

```
private static final String MYAPPTAG= YourActivity.class.getName();
```

Then you put the log code in a method:

```
Log.d(MYAPPTAG, String.valueOf(stringDueDate));
```

You will need to make sure you set your filter properly in `logCat` settings.

I suggest you to concatenate with a string to make sure something prints to the console just incase the value is null, for example:

```
Log.d(MYAPPTAG, "stringDueDate = " + stringDueDate);
```

Comment: Ok, I will try that and thanks for the concatenate advice.

Comment: No luck.  I ran with a Log Tag of "MYAPPTAG" in LogCat and it shows nothing.  I then ran with no Filter and I just see lines and lines of other info with no MYAPPTAG anywhere.   Thoughts?

Comment: You need to filter on your app package name `com.company.appname`

Comment: Yes, Android Studio pre-populates the FilterName and the Package Name so those were set.

FilterName:  ThirdScreen
Log Tag (regex): MYAPPTAG
Pakcage Name:  com.example.xyz.thirdscreen

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
public class CardViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "CLOCKS";
private ListenerEditText eListenerEditText;

eListenerEditText.setKeyImeChangeListener(new KeyImeChange() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            int stringNotes2 = eListenerEditText.getText().toString().trim().length();
            Log.d(TAG, "Length - " + stringNotes2));
        }
}
```

If this doesn't work then there must be something wrong with your listener. I'll highly recommend to use TextWatcher on EditText over KeyListener.

Comment: No luck.  Why do you recommend TextWatcher rather than KeyImeChangeListener?

Comment: Because TextWatcher is recommend and more efficient way of dealing with EditText text change. It does not rely on IME to find the text change and works directly with EditText.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  It is amazing to me how complicated a simple task like outputing a String is with Android.  Even though I'm new to Android, it shouldn't take hours to get the output.  And I still don't have a solution.  I can rewrite listener code to use TextWatcher but that will take days!

Answer (score 0):

**Log.i:** Use this to post useful information to the log. For example: that you have successfully connected to a server. Basically use it to report successes.

> Log.i(String tag, String msg);